Why when I want to swap my ethereum on phantom it says I done have enough
I have 500 dollars in my phantom wallet but I want to swap my ethereum to other criptos and when I want to swap my cripto, the phantom app says I don’t have enough ethereum when I do.

Same issue just now. Did the transfer. Phantom wallet shows I have the full amount. But swap interface says I have 1/4 of the total amount.
